# Is this winter hat SE thing prompting an increase in reduced quality of questions?

Tags: discussion

Is this winter hat SE thing prompting an increase in reduced quality of questions?

I have seena lot of people asking poor quality questions and giving an instant answer.

Comment: Example(s)? (nt)

Answer (score 3):

I think the ultimate thing to bare in mind is the following from the [Winter Bash FAQ](http://winterba.sh/faq).

> All normal site rules still apply. If you get suspended, you're disqualified from hats for the duration of your suspension. If you're caught sockpuppeting for hats, you will be suspended, just as you would be normally.

The first self-answered question I saw after the start of the Winter Bash was [this one](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30619/what-is-the-meaning-of-w-and-t-in-zoom-button), although at the time I was unaware that there was a hat for that kind of thing. I considered the question without being aware that it could being used to game hats, and decided that although fairly simple, it is the sort of thing that is likely to be searched for in Google and the like, and a decent answer could draw novice photographers to our site, which is surely a good thing.

I think we should weigh each question on merit. If a question isn't good enough, then it shouldn't be here. Likewise answers and comments that duplicate existing answers and comments without adding anything should probably be removed. It'll add a bit more work to those users with the necessary powers, but by the same token it'll help to develop the community and increase participation.

Comment: these are great points

Comment: I guess my feeling was I had seen an increase in activity this morning and put 2+2 together and actually got 5